# why get_post_meta is returning 0?

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, post-meta

I'm trying to show all the posts on a page with an audio player in it and for that I'm looping through posts in the following manner:

```
<?php

$posts = get_posts();
$ID;
foreach( $posts as $item)
{
 global $post;
 $post_id = $item->ID;
 $file_id = get_post_meta($post_id, 'sound_s', true);
 $file_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $file_id );
 $attr = array(
'src'      => $file_url,
'loop'     => '',
'autoplay' => '',
'preload'  => 'none'
    );
    echo wp_audio_shortcode( $attr );

    $ID = $file_id;
    var_dump($file_id);
}

?>
```

But trying to echo or var_dump $file_id is returning in null due to which my audio player can not be shown. And yeah there's no mistake in meta key and $post_id is also returning currect value. So please tell me why is this happening?

Comment: The code you've given seems fine. Your site must not be storing this value the way you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code and check if '**sound_s**' key exists in the array or not

```
$file_id = get_post_meta($post_id);
echo "<pre>";
print_r( $file_id );
exit;
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you try to change the third attributes of **get_post_meta()** to **false**

```
$file_id = get_post_meta($post_id, 'sound_s', false);
```

and then access your variable by

```
var_dump($file_id[0]);
```

Comment: Sorry but It didn't work.